# How do I enforce a maximum depth and value requirements for a multi-dimensional object containing objects and arrays of primitive (only) values?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, type-safety

##### Introduction:

I have a multi-dimension object in a TypeScript file, that would look something like this:

```js
const store = {
  key_1: "value",
  key_2: 123,
  key_3: true,
  key_4: {
    key_4_1: "value",
    key_4_2: 123,
    key_4_3: false,
    key_4_4: [
      "value_4_4_1",
      "value_4_4_2",
      "value_4_4_3",
    ]
  },
  key_5: [
    "value_5_1",
    "value_5_2",
    "value_5_3",
  ],
  value_5: {
    key_1: "copy-pasted-from-parent-object",
    key_2: 123,
    key_3: true,
    key_4: {
      key_4_1: "value",
      key_4_2: 123,
      key_4_3: false,
      key_4_4: [
        "value_4_4_1",
        "value_4_4_2",
        "value_4_4_3",
      ]
    },
    key_5: [
      "value_5_1",
      "value_5_2",
      "value_5_3",
    ]
  }
};
```

Please note that the order, key count, length, value and size of each object and it's child objects/arrays/values can vary from object to object and have no bearing on the final result.

##### Background:

I want to create an `interface` or `type` that enforces the following rules:

1. Values in arrays and objects (where the value is not an array or another nested object) must be of type `number`, `boolean`, or `string`.
2. There can never be any `undefined`, `null`, or `NaN` values.
3. Numbers can never have a negative value (**I.E:** less than `0`).
4. String values can never be empty.
5. The object cannot have more than 4 dimensions (4 nested objects).
6. Arrays will never have nested objects or arrays.
7. The values of array items will always be of type `string`.
8. All keys for all objects must be of type `string`.

##### Solution 1 and the outcome:

Here is the interface I've tried to use as the type for this object:

```js
interface Store {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | string[] | Store;
}
```

However, this does not enforce rules `3`, `4`, or `5`.

##### Solution 2 (for rules `3` and `4`) and the outcome:

To simplify the type checking for rules `3` and `4`, I've implemented a loop function that checks the values of strings (boils down to `string.length > 0 && number >= 0`) and used `throw new TypeError(...)` to notify me of a mistake.

##### Question:

How do I change this `interface` or use a better `type` to enforce these rules in a more efficient way?

Comment: No `NaN` values is impossible to enforce.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpQRbW) meet your needs? Please test thoroughly before replying because there are LOTS of edge cases.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It works for objects with `string`, `string[]`, `boolean` and `number` values but not `object` values. Also, during testing I found this to be a very complex and intricate way of implementing the desired functionality. I've instead opted to break the object into two separate objects and use a JavaScript function to ensure the values (**I.E.** `x > -1` and `s.length > 0`, etc...). Might not be as efficient as using TypeScript but it is the simplest and easiest-to-understand way of getting this done. That said, thank you very much for your time. I genuinely appreciate your advice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it not working for `object` (a [mre] of the issue is always helpful) but presumably the point is moot because you've given up on doing it in the type system.